# How to create a geometric pattern stroke in Illustrator (with some constraints)?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush

I want to make the stroke to the left (the green part counts):

[image: output]

All I can come up with is a pattern stroke to the right, but as you can see it is just not right. Every second corner will not align nicely, which makes sense, of course, but how could I tackle this?

[image: pattern brush def]

Answer (score 1):

Every second corner will not line up nicely because your Side Tile has alternating positions (the line "entering" the left side is lower than the line "exiting" the right side), but your Outer Corner Tile has 2 lines who are equidistant from the inner corner.

They key is to take measurements of your "entrance/exit" points and make sure they match the pattern you are trying to build.  In the following example, the corner has been adjusted so that it's "southern" line will align with the "upper" line from the side tile.

[image]

Comment: Now the line (not corner) part will not fit as I will get top-bottom-top|top-bottom-top...

Comment: @JanLimpens Good point.  Updating the answer to remove the adjusted side tile.

Comment: Now one corner element is longer than all others. This breaks the intended visual appearance. I start to think, that this is simply not possible in illustrator (which is weird because of the supposedly simple nature of the stroke).